# Android studio build issue Google sign in and Firebase latest version 10.2.4

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

Android studio build issue Google sign in and Firebase latest version 10.2.4
google sign in was working fine until I have put firebase jar in gradle and its throwing "Error:(149, 28) The type com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.AbstractSafeParcelable cannot be found in source files, imported jack libs or the classpath"
below is app level build
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "viksit.com.viksit.pro.viksitpro"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2') {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        }

        android {
            useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
        }
        compile project(':linkedin-sdk')

        compile(group: 'org.simpleframework', name: 'simple-xml', version: '2.7.1') {
            exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
        }

        compile('com.udojava:EvalEx:1.0') {
            exclude group: 'junit', module: 'junit'
        }


        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.2'
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
        compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.18.0'
        compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.4.2'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.4'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.4'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.4'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.4'
        compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.2'
        compile 'com.felipecsl:gifimageview:2.1.0'
        compile 'me.itangqi.waveloadingview:library:0.3.5'
        compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
        compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
        compile 'com.github.vipulasri:timelineview:1.0.5'
        compile 'com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.1.0'
        compile 'com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:3.0.0-RC1'
        compile 'com.truizlop.sectionedrecyclerview:library:1.2.0'
        compile 'com.github.castorflex.verticalviewpager:library:19.0.1'
        compile 'link.fls:swipestack:0.3.0'
        compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.3'
        compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
        compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
        compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.+'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
```

below is project level build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'


    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: You put `gms:google-services:3.0.0'` in the wrong place... It isn't an app dependency. And it goes at the bottom. And you have mismatched versions of the support libraries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you skipped this step

> `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` line be at the **bottom** of your `app/build.gradle file`

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin

Sidenote: You have Glide and Picasso, two-way gif drawable libraries, and two shaped imageview libraries.  Each pair do the same thing. Clean out your dependencies to reduce your app size and chances of errors

Comment: Error:(149, 28) The type com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.AbstractSafeParcelable cannot be found in source files, imported jack libs or the classpath

Comment: Well, I don't think the problem is Firebase. `android.gms.common` is not a Firebase package

Comment: this error is coming after integrating firebase i m getting classnoDeFound exception for GoogleSignInOptions

Comment: Also, suggest fixing to `25.3.0` version of the support libraries instead of also `25.0.2`

Comment: That class is from `play-services-auth` dependencies

Comment: i have change version to 25.3.0 for all

Comment: yeah thanks mate its working after taking a decade for rebuilding and cleaning

Comment: It woudn't take as long if you didn't try to compile everything

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar problem with firebase yesterday and this worked for me:
 Just add this to gradle file and rebuild it:

```
android {
 ....
 dexOptions {
    // Prevent OutOfMemory with MultiDex during the build phase
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
  }
}
```

Comment: getting this Error:(149, 28) The type com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.AbstractSafeParcelable cannot be found in source files, imported jack libs or the classpath

Comment: the library isn't being downloaded properly,it's a firebase framework issue,try my solution and if possible clean and rebuild once more..